# nfs unworkable using new managed switch - no idea why - DoS of two ZyXel switches breaks portmap

Tags: networking, nfs, lan

I spent 3 nights and part of days, googling and reconfiguring servers of home network with two nfs vers=3 servers that suddenly stopped working.

They were working with zero issues using automount from 3-4 clients.
This is nothing productive, I have them at home just to test things or so, but there are some photos and movies and so sitting on ZFS on one or the other server.

Nothing worked suddenly, and no progress achieved.. neither rm /etc/default/nfs-* apt-get purge&install, neither various attempts to start rpc.mountd or statd and watch its output.. 
Well, but there is third machine with nfs3 server, a router with OpenWRT serving just an USB key. This one do work with zero troubles from all pcs, regardless of those two Ubuntu servers dead..
So, I did suspect Ubuntu updates. I found nfs-utils package removed few months ago.. And I was not sure when it stopped working.

Symptoms:
showmount -e server takes 2 to 3 minutes to show answer, but answer is correct.
rpcinfo -p server takes around one minute or more, shows right output.
mount.nfs xx:/x/x /mnt/test -o vers=3 ends after minute or two with error.
ping or mount samba of those servers works without troubles, 
iperf says around 1gigabit as expected (or less but still nice when client is using wifi).
telnet to portmapper port and nfs port opens a session. 
Firewall is off. Even added ALL:lanip to  Hosts.allow.
- every trouble regards only Ubuntu servers, OpenWrt one responds in a fraction of second and do work as expected from all clients. But it does not support nfs4.
- one of servers is 12.04.5 LTS with Trusty HWE stack, 
- second server is 14.04 LTS Trusty.
All updates installed.
One of them uses nic bonding (mode0) of two interfaces, second one does not.

Reason, without explanation:

To make long story a bit shorter, few minutes ago I got a crazy idea to try, and exchanged my new ZyXel GS1900-8 managed switch for old cheap (but also gigabit) tplink.
And I went mad, as my NFS servers started working in that moment.

Gazing at the switch, I have no idea what is going wrong with him.
Now I recall that I did enable LLTP and installed lltpd on all pc's, just to have fun seeing their name in port list. 
And I did some testing with bonding using 803.ad LACP which was not supported by old switch and is working on new one, but I turned it off (back to mode 0) as it was avoiding WoL that I am using regullary and consider necessary..

Please tell me what to check, or take some guess of what the reason it could be..
Where to look and what commands to try to find the difference? I got wery curious.

Comment: Well, turning LLDP global DISABLE on ZyXel GS1900-8 solved the problem. What does it mean??  Just a bug in firmware?  I guess I am far from being only one with this problem.

Comment: Oh, well, and when I turned LLDP back ENABLED in switch, my nfs keep working. Now I am completely lost..

Comment: Problem returned overnight with LLDP Enablen on a switch. This time, turning LLDP Global - Disabled did not help.

Comment: Iperf -u -p 111 do work (at 1.25Mbit but this is the same for udp on other ports). Restart of all those servers and switch and all is working again. I have to wait until it breaks again, for more tests.

Comment: Another update, this time leading a bit different way.  I got another managed switch, ZyXel GS1524. This one is old and does not support any LLDP.  Anyway, my problem with NFS appeared here as well.  Thus, GS1900-8 is no more suspect, and  lldpd service gets more into account..  It is version lldpd 0.5.5-1 on one (Precise) server and 0.7.7-1 on another (Trusty), both kernels are 3.13.0-37-generic #64 (one is -precise, thanks to lts hwe enablement stack).   Well, stopped lldpd service on both and restarted the switch and NFS3 works again.  edit: and stop working again soon.

Comment: WELL, enable the anti-Dos checkmark of (only one checkmark):
**Scan SYNFIN
Prevent NULL Scan Attacks
Deny SYN with sport < 1024 **
- And no more NFS,rpcinfo or showmount. Regardless of LLDPD service.. Disable that checkmark, an all is immediately working again. Note that both switches are ZyXEL.. What now?

Comment: I found that turing DoS feature off on original ZyXel GS1900-8 switch helps as well. Here the only single checkmark is for DoS blocking function. This works "online", so I may get NFS working immediately by turning DoS off, on both switches (and while GS1524 breaks NFS almost immediately when enbled DoS, GS1900-8 takes almost whole day to start blocking NFS again).  My problem is solved almost completely, but I am still curious WHY and especially, HOW can I detect a problem in any else way than by hang of client due to blocked NFS server services - leaving the question unanswered. Please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends by finding that managed switches with DoS (denial of service) feature enables, detects SYN<1024 portmap requests and start blocking them. 
Turning this feature off solves the problem completely.

I cant detect the problem otherwise than trying rpcinfo -p or showmount -e, because all ports are accesible when trying just telnet.

Google found common messages, after I already know what to search, e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/367107/cant-mount-nfs-share-over-tcp
And different brands of switches are mentioned (mine are ZyXel, their PoweConnect and also Cisco).

IMHO, with managed switches getting cheap and common, this problem may reappear may times, and perhaps is the reason for another nfs troubles mentioned on askubuntu.